# global objects and passing by reference

Tags: javascript

I have a global variable 'globalProperty' and assign it to a property of an object'.

```
var globalProperty = 'hello';

function func1(){
   obj['prop'] = globalProperty;

   //code....

   obj['prop'] = 'good'.
}
```

I want my obj[prop] to reference the global variable. SO if I modify the obj[prop], the global variable will also be modified to 'good'.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't provide a way to assign variables by reference, so that's not possible (without you implementing some way to update both, the object and the variable).

Comment: Javascript does not support that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

javascript always use by value for passing params, you can still create a global object and modify its properties , for example

```
 var globalObject= new Object();
 globalObject.text = 'Hello';

 function func1() {
    obj = {};
    obj['prop'] = globalObject;
        console.log(globalObject.text);
    obj['prop'].text = 'good';
        console.log(globalObject.text);
}

 func1();
```